# How to structure various interdependent Schemas in mongoose OR how to use 'reference' properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently working on a vocabulary application using node.js, Express, MongoDB and mongoose.

**My aim**: Putting out translations for various languages depending on the choices made in the front-end (E. g.: German > English, English > Portuguese etc.)

**Main problem**: Interdependent Schemas. The translation of a word stored in `WordSchema` depends on the language represented by the `LanguageSchema`.

For me, there appear two different ways on how to structure the relevant `Schemas`:

**1.**
There is one `Schema` representing the language (e.g. German, Englisch,...). It stores several words according to the language. Because `Word` represents another `Schema` it is referenced to the `WordSchema` inside the `LanguageSchema`. The **problem** which appears here is that the values of the word depend on the chosen language.

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var LanguageSchema = new Schema({
    language: String, // 'German'
    words: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Word'}] 
    // word: 'Haus' instead of e. g. 'house'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Language', LanguageSchema);

var WordSchema = new Schema({
    name: String // 'house', 'Haus', 'casa' depending on the language
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Word', WordSchema);
```

**2.** I could solve this by using just the `WordSchema` and adding all the languages which exist as a property and add the according translation of the word. But this doesn't seem the best working solution for me as I won't translate the words into all languages right from the beginning. So there just should be stored those translations for a word where there actually exists a translation.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the relation between WordSchema and LanguageSchema are,

Comment: Every language consists of the same words. The meaning of the word is the same in every language (means it wouldn't make sense to create for instance 30 'new Word' all with the same meaning just another translation. So the set of words can be the same, just different translations according to the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LanguageSchema**

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var LanguageSchema = new Schema({
    language_name: {type:String}, // English
    language_code: {type:String}  // en
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Language', LanguageSchema);
```

In Word Schema , you need to push objects with `word_name` and `word_language`

**WordSchema**

```
var WordSchema = new Schema({
    words:[{
                  word_name:{type:String},
                  word_language:{type:String}
                 }]
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Word', WordSchema);
```

Example : Language in Database

```
    languages : [
                  { 
                    "_id":"54ef3f374849dcaa649a3abc", 
                    "language_name":"English" , 
                    "language_code":"en"
                  },
                  {
                   "_id":54ef3f374849dcaa649a3asd",   
                   "language_name":"Portuguese" , 
                   "language_code":"pt"
                   },
                  {
                   "_id":54ef3f374849dcaa649a3xxx", 
                   "language_name":"German" ,
                   "language_code":"de"},
                ]
```

Example :  Words in Database

```
  words:[
       {
       word:[
        {
         "_id":"54ef3f374849dcaa649azzz", 
         "word_name":"Friend" ,
         "word_language":"English"
        },

        {
         "_id":"54ef3f374849dcaa6491111",
         "word_name":"Amigo" ,
         "word_language":"Portuguese"
        },
        {
        "_id":"54ef3f374849dcaa649a233",
        "word_name":"Freund" ,
        "word_language":"German"
        },
       ]
     },
     { word: [...] },
     { word: [...] },
     { word: [...] },
     { word: [...] }
 ]
```

from frontend you have to pass 3 parameters

> word , input_language , output_language

Example : You want "Friend" meaning from English to Portuguese

so in this case :

> word="Friend" , input_language="English" ,
>   output_language="Portuguese"

Now Applying Mongoose Find Query and search Word in WordSchema

```
Word.findOne({word_name:{ $regex:word, $options: "$i" },word_language:input_language},function(err,result){
    if(err){ return err;}
    if(!err && result){
 //  now you have to use underscore.js and find out result by output language 

//  http://underscorejs.org
// . npm i --save underscore 

      var outputObj= _.find(result.word, { word_language :output_language});

      res.json(outputObj);

    }
})
```